# When I enter the admin panel I get an error DoesNotExist at /admin/login/ Site matching query does not exist

Tags: python, html, django, admin

When I enter the admin panel I get an error. I go through `localhost:8000/admin`
If you want, I will throw off the code of how I did the registration and settinngs

I logged into the admin panel recently, and after that I worked with registrations and after that I could not log in, but I deleted everything I did and returned everything to its original form when I still entered but still had an error

setings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'MainPage',
    'news',
    'registration',
    'comment',
    'cabinet',
    'haystack',
    'programs',
    'lessons_django',
    'lessons_java',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'bootstrap4',
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'taggit',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RapterGames.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'RapterGames.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/blog'
    },
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('news.urls')),
    path('news/',include('news.urls')),
    path('', include('registration.urls')),
    path('', include('comment.urls')),
    path('', include('cabinet.urls')),
    path('programms/', include('programs.urls')),
    path('', include('programs.urls')),
    path('lessons_java/', include('lessons_java.urls')),
    path('', include('lessons_java.urls')),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Traceback:

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py" in _get_site_by_request
  39.                 SITE_CACHE[host] = self.get(domain__iexact=host)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  408.                 self.model._meta.object_name

During handling of the above exception (Site matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in login
  399.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in dispatch
  61.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  133.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in get_context_data
  95.         current_site = get_current_site(self.request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\shortcuts.py" in get_current_site
  13.         return Site.objects.get_current(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py" in get_current
  60.             return self._get_site_by_request(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py" in _get_site_by_request
  45.                 SITE_CACHE[domain] = self.get(domain__iexact=domain)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  408.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Add `INSTALLED_APPS` from `setting.py` and `urls.py` in your question

Comment: Ok ? i add settings and urls in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `SITE_ID` setting in your settings file is pointing to an ID that doesn't exist in your database.

Set `SITE_ID=1` in `settings.py`